# Combine image with its mask with Android shaders?

Tags: java, android, opengl-es, shader

I'm developing an app for android and I use GL for some behaivors and I have a problem with an specific case.

I have an image of an ambient (for example, a room), and also y have a mask that is all white and marks in black the location of the a wall.

Well I want to make a mix with this two images and get the result (for example, tint the wall in red)

But first at all I need to indicate to the shader who are the two images, and here I have troubles.

Here is my fragment shader:

```
public static final String fs_Image_mix =
        "precision mediump float;" +

                "arying LOWP vec4 v_color;" +
                "varying vec2 v_texCoord;" +

                "uniform sampler2D s_texture;" +
                "uniform sampler2D s_mask;" +

                "void main() {" +
                //"  gl_FragColor = texture2D( s_texture, v_texCoord );" +

                "   vec4 color0 = texture2D(s_texture, v_texCoords);" +
                "   vec4 color1 = texture2D(s_mask, v_texCoords);" +

                "   float mask = texture2D(s_mask, v_texCoords).a;" +
                "   mask = step(1.0, mask);" +

                "   gl_FragColor = v_color * mix(color0, color1, mask);" +
                "}";
```

And here is my Draw function were I pass the background texture:

```
public void Draw(float[] mvpMatrix, int[] textureHandle, int textureIndex){

    GLES20.glActiveTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE0);

    // Apply transparency to the texture
    GLES20.glEnable(GLES20.GL_BLEND);
    GLES20.glBlendFunc(GLES20.GL_SRC_ALPHA, GLES20.GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);

    // Ensure that uses the correct texture
    GLES20.glBindTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureHandle[textureIndex]);

    // get handle to vertex shader's vPosition member
    int mPositionHandle = GLES20.glGetAttribLocation(GraphicTools.sp_Image_mix, "vPosition");

    // Enable generic vertex attribute array
    GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(mPositionHandle);

    // Prepare the triangle coordinate data
    GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(mPositionHandle, COORDS_PER_VERTEX,
            GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false,
            vertexStride, vertexBuffer);

    // Get handle to texture coordinates location
    int mTexCoordLoc = GLES20.glGetAttribLocation(GraphicTools.sp_Image_mix, "a_texCoord" );

    // Enable generic vertex attribute array
    GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray ( mTexCoordLoc );

    // Prepare the texturecoordinates
    GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer ( mTexCoordLoc, 2, GLES20.GL_FLOAT,
            false,
            0, uvBuffer);

    // Get handle to shape's transformation matrix
    int mtrxhandle = GLES20.glGetUniformLocation(GraphicTools.sp_Image_mix, "uMVPMatrix");

    // Apply the projection and view transformation
    GLES20.glUniformMatrix4fv(mtrxhandle, 1, false, mvpMatrix, 0);

    // Get handle to textures locations
    int mSamplerLoc = GLES20.glGetUniformLocation (GraphicTools.sp_Image_mix, "s_texture" );

    // Set the sampler texture unit to 0, where we have saved the texture.
    GLES20.glUniform1i ( mSamplerLoc, 0);

    // Draw the triangle
    GLES20.glDrawElements(GLES20.GL_TRIANGLES, indices.length,
            GLES20.GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, drawListBuffer);

    // Disable vertex array
    GLES20.glDisableVertexAttribArray(mPositionHandle);
    GLES20.glDisableVertexAttribArray(mTexCoordLoc);

}
```

How can I fill "s_mask" variable with desired mask? remember that textureHandle[textureIndex] is the background image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Access to the texture and the mask texture

The value you pass to the texture sampler uniform is the index of the texture unit to which the texture
you want to pass is bound. To use multiple textures in a shader, you should do the following:

Once the shader the shader stages are compiled and the shader program is linked 
you can get the uniform locations of the texture sampler.

```
int mTextureSamplerLoc = GLES20.glGetUniformLocation( GraphicTools.sp_Image_mix, "s_texture" );
int mMaskSamplerLoc    = GLES20.glGetUniformLocation( GraphicTools.sp_Image_mix, "s_mask" );
```

Before you draw the scene, the textures have to be bound to the texture units.

```
int textureTexUnitIndex = 1;
GLES20.glActiveTexture( GLES20.GL_TEXTURE1 ); // GLES20.GL_TEXTURE1 <--> textureTexUnitIndex
GLES20.glBindTexture( GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureHandle[textureIndex] );

int maskTexUnitIndex = 2;
GLES20.glActiveTexture( GLES20.GL_TEXTURE2 ); // GLES20.GL_TEXTURE2 <--> maskTexUnitIndex
GLES20.glBindTexture( GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, ... ) // <-- here you have to add the texture handler of the texture
```

When you use the shader program you have to set the texture unit indices to the texture sampler uniforms:

```
GLES20.glUniform1i( mTextureSamplerLoc, textureTexUnitIndex );
GLES20.glUniform1i( mMaskSamplerLoc, maskTexUnitIndex );
```

Note, I use the texture units 1 and 2 but you can use any texture units you want. The only requirement is to use 2 different texture units.

#### Tint the wall

> I have an image of an ambient (for example, a room), and also y have a mask that is all white and marks in black the >location of the a wall.
>   Well I want to make a mix with this two images and get the result (for example, tint the wall in red)

I assume that your texture is a RGB texture and the mask is a black and white texture with at least one channel (R).
With these conditions, your fragment shader has to look somehow like this:

```
precision mediump float;

varying LOWP vec4 v_color;
varying vec2 v_texCoord;

uniform sampler2D s_texture;
uniform sampler2D s_mask;

void main()
{
    vec3  texCol  = texture2D( s_texture, v_texCoord ).rgb;
    float maskCol = texture2D( s_mask, v_texCoord ).r;
    vec3 finalCol = s_texture.rgb * mix( v_color.rgb, vec3(1.0), maskCol );
    gl_FragColor  = vec4( finalCol, 1.0 );
}
```

Comment: Well it works for me, I need to implement more behaviors but now I can advance, it was really helpful for me